Не работает агент для записи данных в файл
вот так выглядит агент для записи шуток в файл:
def get_sales_tool(self):
    wd      = os.getcwd()
    llm     = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.0, model_name="gpt-4-0125-preview")
    toolkit = FileManagementToolkit(root_dir = wd)
    tools   = toolkit.get_tools()
    
    FORMAT_INSTRUCTIONS = """
        Используйте следующий формат:
        Вопрос: шутки, которые нужно запомнить и записать в файл jokes.txt.
        Мысль: всегда нужно думать о том, что делать и как записать в файл jokes.txt шутки
        Действие: обновить данные файла jokes.txt, если файла не существует, то создать его и добавить в него шутки
        Ввод действия: ввод действия.
        Наблюдение: результат действия
        ... (эта мысль/действие/действие/ввод/наблюдение может повторяться N раз)
    """
    PREFIX = """Создай файл jokes.txt если его не существует и запиши в него все данные которые тебе придут, а именно шутки"""
    SUFFIX = """
        Begin!
        Question: {input}
        Thought: {agent_scratchpad}
    """

    agent   = initialize_agent(
        tools,
        llm,
        agent                 = AgentType.STRUCTURED_CHAT_ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
        verbose               = True,
        agent_executor_kwards = { "handle_parsing_errors": True },
        early_stopping_method = "generate",
        agent_kwargs          = {
            "prefix"             : PREFIX,
            "format_instructions": FORMAT_INSTRUCTIONS,
            "suffix"             : SUFFIX
        }
    )

    return agent

вывод в консоле такой:
> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
Question: моя шутка: смешная шутка
Thought: Пользователь предоставил все необходимые данные для записи шутки. Нужно использовать инструмент "Запись шутки".
Action: Запись шутки
Action Input: смешная шутка

> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
Action: write_file
Input: {
  "file_path": "jokes.txt",
  "text": "смешная шутка",
  "append": false
}

> Finished chain.

Observation: Action: write_file
Input: {
  "file_path": "jokes.txt",
  "text": "смешная шутка",
  "append": false
}
Thought:I now know the final answer
Final Answer: Ваша шутка записана

но в файл ничего не записывается, он пустой

доступ на изменение файла у меня стоит для всех пользователей, работает с файлом конкретно в этой директории потому что раньше также создавал файлы там, в любом случае не обновляет его

wd содержит корневую директорию проекта, все верно, там находится файл jokes.txt в который нейронка должна заносить мои смешные шутки

попробовал сам программно записать случайный текст в файл, все получилось, также пробовал менять название файла и добавлять текст в новый файл все получается, агент опять же не может этого сделать, также иногда появляются вот такие логи:
Thought:Could not parse LLM output: Я не могу выполнить эту операцию.
